# empty options when bootstrap-select is reopen from being closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm wanting to use the [bootstrap-select jQuery plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to bring style and additional functionality to standard select elements in my UI. When the dropdown is expanded and then closed, when the user reopens it... the list of selectable elements is completely empty.

[image]
[image]

I've created a very quick screencast to demo the bug:
https://youtu.be/3uGBymNz9is

A very hacky fix to the issue seems to be making sure that when the button's clicked, the `<div class="dropdown-menu">` element that the plugin creates gets an `open` class applied to it.. which is happening by the plugin the first time the dropdown is expanded but not subsequent times for some reason.

Is there's something in the use the plugin that's causing this behaviour or something I need to do to prevent it?

Comment: post your code with jsfiddle or snippets?

Comment: hmm the jsfiddle is working...

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a conflict with dropdown-enhancements plugin. The fix is to remove that plugin and pick out the functionality i actually need and implement it myself. The dropdown-enhancements plugin doesn't have a way to only apply it's functionality to certain `select` elements